# Get href attribute of link using Xpath

Tags: php, html, xpath

I've been trying to figure out how to get the href attribute of a link found on a external webpage.

Here is an example page that I am trying to parse with Xpath:

http://www.shazam.com/track/234782921/lean-on

What I'm trying to get is the following href attribute only of the first element in the list:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqeW9_5kURI" class="vd-box vd-play"><span></span></a>
```

FROM

```
<div id="trackVideos" class="panel__body">
  <ul class="vd-list">
    <li class="vd-elm" data-beacon="{&quot;type&quot;: &quot;videoclick&quot;}">
      <div class="vd-box" style="background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YqeW9_5kURI/hqdefault.jpg);filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YqeW9_5kURI/hqdefault.jpg,sizingMethod=scale);"></div>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqeW9_5kURI" class="vd-box vd-play"><span></span></a>
      <div class="vd-data">
        <p class="vd-title">Major Lazer &amp; DJ Snake - Lean On (feat. MØ) (Official Music Video)</p>

        <p class="vd-details">484,920,908 <span>views</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    
  <li>SECOND LI</li>
  <li>THIRD</li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

This is what I tried:

```
foreach ($xpath->query("//ul[@class='vd-list']/li[1]/a/@href") as $attr) {
    $link = $attr->value;
    echo $link;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, if the answer is correct I'm giving you, but i think with setting the variable `$link` in the foreach, you set it all the time, and nothing will appear...

However, this code should work:

```
<?php

$a = '<div id="trackVideos" class="panel__body">
  <ul class="vd-list">
    <li class="vd-elm" data-beacon="{&quot;type&quot;: &quot;videoclick&quot;}">
      <div class="vd-box" style="background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YqeW9_5kURI/hqdefault.jpg);filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YqeW9_5kURI/hqdefault.jpg,sizingMethod=scale);"></div>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqeW9_5kURI" class="vd-box vd-play"><span></span></a>
      <div class="vd-data">
        <p class="vd-title">Major Lazer &amp; DJ Snake - Lean On (feat. MØ) (Official Music Video)</p>

        <p class="vd-details">484,920,908 <span>views</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>

  <li>SECOND LI</li>
  <li>THIRD</li>

  </ul>

</div>';

$xpath = simplexml_load_string($a);

foreach ($xpath->xpath("//ul[@class='vd-list']/li[1]/a/@href") as $attr) {
    echo $attr;  
}

?>
```